# Uninstall SAGE on Linux machines (Fedora or Ubuntu)

Tags: python-2.7, uninstallation, sage

How do I uninstall SAGE after I have installed it according to the [SAGE site](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/installation/binary.html#linux-and-os-x)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can't (yet) install Sage using `pip`, uninstalling it this way wouldn't work either.  If you installed Sage directly as a binary (as you indicate in your question), you just remove the binary (and remove the `.sage/` directory as well, perhaps).  All the other stuff are just prereqs for Sage and wouldn't harm you to keep them (e.g. `gfortran`).  Sage shouldn't be using "system" Python anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is no clean way.

```
pip freeze | grep sage
pip uninstall sage
```

do not remove SAGE. Further deleting the `SageMath` directory won't solve the issue. Only removing through `yum` or `dnf` will make the deal. Yet at the cost that this will reset python to the system `python` and remove `gcc`, `g++` and `gfortran`. But it is not a big deal after all, to reinstall python scientific stack and the compilers.